# Quotes on the value of hard work, perseverance, struggling in math

Tags: soft-question, big-list

Have you come across a quote that emphasizes the value of hard work, perseverance, struggling, etc. in mathematics? Do share.

Some examples:

- "Does one have to be a genius to do mathematics? The answer is an emphatic NO." - [Terry Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/does-one-have-to-be-a-genius-to-do-maths/)
- "It's bad to have too good a memory if you want to be a mathematician." - [Andrew Wiles](https://plus.maths.org/content/andrew-wiles-what-does-if-feel-do-maths)
- "Struggling is a good thing... it's where learning happens, it's what we professors are always doing in our research... the struggle is the most interesting place to be." - [Francis Su](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rpspyvzgcrdbcru/Su_The%20Value%20of%20Struggle.pdf?dl=0)

(and of course Bill Thurston's excellent [Overflow profile](https://mathoverflow.net/users/9062/bill-thurston).)

Comment: *"Does one have to be a genius to do mathematics? The answer is an emphatic NO. **But honestly, I have no idea about that, because I AM a genius.**"* - Terry Tao, as I like to think.

Comment: You do you judge to be genius?

Comment: @Wuestenfux: I am not judging myself (I am a poor dumb soul), I was judging Terry Tao to be a genius.

Comment: I love one due to Paul Dirac. See the quote starting with the words *If you are...*, here from [Wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Paul_Dirac). I say the quote that you can read next-to-last of the section *Quotes*, before *The Principles of Quantum Mechanics*. But I take it as an idealization, because my thougths are that even with a great effort I will be unable to do same calculations and reasonings that can do a professional mathematician.